# How to automatically use Windows credential of the server in a java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I want to read the contents of a sharepoint website, however since this requires login credentials I receive a HTTP Unauthorized 401 error. My set up is basically a Tomcat server running on an Windows machine, and what I want is to deploy a servlet on the Tomcat server. This servlet when receives a request should use the credentials of the server Windows machine and parse the sharepoint website.

Could anyone point me to an example in order to achieve this?

Comment: Are you meaning `LDAP` integration in tomcat?

Comment: look into this, whether it can solve your problem: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html